# Matlab mesh plot. Specific function for z. Z must be a matrix

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

I'd like to make a function, that will be making a mesh plot.
start x,y; dx,dy and end x,y will be inputted into a function.
Z should be calculated like there:

```
if x>y
     z =x^2-sin(x);
elseif x==y
     z = 3;
else
     z = 2*x+2*x;
end
```

I've made this code:

```
function []= mes(xp,xk,dx,yp,yk,dy)
x=[xp:dx:xk];
y=[yp:dy:yk];
zv=[];

for i=1:numel(x)
        if x>y
            z=x(i)^2-sin(y(i));
        elseif x(i)==y(i)
            z=3;
        else
            z=2*x(i)+2*y(i);    
        end
    zv=[zv z];
end
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
figure
x
y
zv
mesh(X,Y,zv)
```

and got these error codes:

```
Error using mesh (line 70)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

Error in mes (line 21)
mesh(X,Y,zv)
```

Equation for z seems to work.
I know, that there are many answers to simillar problems as mine, but when I make a simple equation for z it works, but not with this one.

Comment: `zv=reshape(zv,[length(x) length(y)])` ?

Comment: function []= mes(xp,xk,dx,yp,yk,dy)
x=[xp:dx:xk];
y=[yp:dy:yk];
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
zv=[];

for i=1:numel(x)
        if x>y
            z=x(i)^2-sin(y(i));
        elseif x(i)==y(i)
            z=3;
        else
            z=2*x(i)+2*y(i);    
        end
    zv=[zv z];
end
zv=reshape(zv,[length(x) length(y)])
figure
mesh(zv)

Yea, mesh plot shows up, but it seems to be wierd, not 3d one. @ander-biguri

Comment: Cosnider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vectorization!

```
x=[xp:dx:xk];
y=[yp:dy:yk];
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

z=zeros(size(X));

z=2*X+2*Y; 
z(X>Y)=X((X>Y)).^2-sin(Y((X>Y)));
z(X==Y)=3; % Careful with floating points!! maybe abs(X-Y)<0.00001 ?

mesh(X,Y,Z);
```